# Display EditText items on Spinner selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have a group of items in spinner and on their click I want to show the respective text in EditText . How I can achieve this. I thought of using switch but it doesnot work for strings. I want someone to tell me right approach for doing this.

I want the EditText array(mysuburb) to respond accordingly to the Spinner items(mystate) click .

Code:-

```
    String[] mysuburb =new String[]{"sub1" ,"sub2","sub3","sub4","sub5","sub6"};




    String[] mystate= new String[]{"NSW","Victoria","Qld","NT","WA","SA"};      
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow, mystate);
   // LTRadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    state.setAdapter(adapter);  

            state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            sstate =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    /*  String sub= state.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();

                        if(sub=="sub1")
                            suburb.setText("sub1") ;  */



                             suburb.setText(arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()); 



                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: what you had tried.? show your code.

Comment: Are you using Bean class objects to fill spinner? Show code first.

Answer (score 1):

```
 state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int i, long l) {

            sstate =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();
            suburb.setText(sstate);
```

}
}

Comment: Please also add where to write this line of code, as in spinner item selected callback?